# Swift Sequence Anamorphism

Tags: swift, sequence, anamorphism

Does Swift's standard library include a [list anamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) for a `Sequence` or something similar?

An Anamorphism on lists or sequences would be the opposite of the `reduce` function. So instead of collapsing a sequence down to a single value, it will build a sequence up.

`reduce` takes an initial value, and a function for combining sequence elements with this, and returns a final value. It's signature looks like this (newlines added for readability):

```
public func reduce<Result>(
  _ initialResult: Result, 
  _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Self.Element) throws -> Result) rethrows
  -> Result
```

An anamorphism for sequence might go like this:

```
func inflate<State, Element>(
  _ initialState: State, 
  _ generator: @escaping (State) -> (State, Element)?)
  -> AnamorphismSequence<State, Element>
```

By giving it some initial state, and telling it how to turn that in to an element and the next state, it can build up a sequence for you. So, I could get an array such as `Array(1..<10)` like this:

```
Array(inflate(1) { s in s < 10 ? (s+1, s) : nil })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has two variants of this. Both types have private initializers, but they can instead be generated using their respective global functions.

1. [`UnfoldSequence<Element, State>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unfoldsequence), which is produced by [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2011998-sequence)
2. [`UnfoldFirstSequence<Element>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unfoldfirstsequence) which is produced by [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence)

The latter doesn't do anything that can't be done by the former. It's merely a simplified version, that's used when you don't need a separate state, beyond merely knowing what the previous element was.

Here's how your `1..<10` example can be implemented, using both methods:

```
Array(sequence(first: 1) { i in (i < 9) ? (i + 1) : nil })

Array(sequence(state: 1) { state -> Int? in 
    defer { state += 1 }
    return state < 10 ? state : nil
})
```

Your example is better suited to the simpler `sequence(first:next:)`. The latter would be more useful for something like a sequence that yields perfect squares:
 * Your maintained state would be the squares of the perfect squares (which increment by 1 with every unfold)
 * Your sequence yields it elements by multiplying that state by itself (to square it)

Technically, you could use a captured local variable to emulate the state of an `UnfoldSequence`, but that's quite a bit messier, and almost certainly slower.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you Alex. A much better answer than my own (now deleted)!